# Caesar Cipher code error: String index out of bounds

Tags: java, stringindexoutofbounds

I'm doing a Caesar Cipher assignment for my grade 11 computer science class. I looked over my code many times, changing it, but nothing I do works and I don't understand why.

The error it's giving me is java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
import java.util.*;

//Caesar Cipher
public class CCTry1
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        //scanner
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);


        //make an array with all the letters
        char[] alphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

        //prompt user for a message
        System.out.println("Enter your message.");
        String message = scanner.nextLine();

        //*******ENCRYPTING******

        System.out.println("Enter your shift number.");
        int shift = scanner2.nextInt();

        //find index of each letter of the user's message, then add the shift number
        //to obtain the new message

        char newletter;
        //for loop to encrypt
        for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
        {

            //take the i letter
            char letter = message.charAt(i);

            //check if that letter = a
            if (letter == alphabet[i])
            {

                //if letter = a, then the new letter is a+shift
                newletter = alphabet[i+shift];

                //if letter is capitalized, convert it to a capital then print
                if(Character.isUpperCase(letter))
                {
                    System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase(newletter));
                }
                //else, just print it as is
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(newletter);
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're iterating over the alphabet, and using the same for loop index, i, to iterate over your message, `message.charAt(i);`. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your shift logic. If you try to shift, for example, a `z` by 5, the index will be out of bounds. You need to "wrap around" at that point. For example, shifting `z` by 2 should actually result in `b` (index 1), *not* index 27.

Also, your `for` loop doesn't make sense because it'll only work if `message` is exactly 26 characters long.

You should iterate over the letters in the message, shifting each one. Make sure you "wrap around." Also, no need for the array of letters.

One more hint: modular arithmetic may come in handy here.